# In tableau, when drawing "sankey" graph, without the initial way "Open with Legacy Connection" how to double original data?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to draw "sankey" graph in tableau.

According to the guidance, the first step would be load data. And instead of just click "open", it should click "open with legacy connection". so that I can chose "Covert to Custom SQL", and then double my original data.

However, I find out that "IMPORTANT: Starting in Tableau 2019.1, you can no longer create a new Legacy Excel or Text connection. Existing workbooks created with these legacy connections will continue to work until 2019.2, when all support for legacy connections will be removed."

I wonder, if there is any replacement for us so that we can still be able to draw **sankey graph**?

Any link or guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need the legacy connection or custom SQL. That was only necessary in the days before Tableau supported Unions.

If you want multiple copies of each data row, then you can simply union a table with itself (a self union). Creating unions when editing a data source is pretty straightforward, and described in the help.

Making sankeys with Tableau is a bit tricky, but possible. Doubling each data row is only one step. If you want to understand how the Sankey works (rather than just follow a recipe of steps), learn about table calcs, domain padding and bin fields. Most sankey approaches use those features in combination. Understanding how those features work and interplay with each other takes some effort but will pay off in other contexts beyond the immediate sankey chart.